# Convert from decimal to a different numeral system in C

Tags: c

I have a task to write a program that converts a number from decimal numeral system to a different numeral system. There are two input values: a decimal number and a base for a new system. I wrote something, but it gives me a "Floating point exception./a.out" error. As much as I know floating point exception means division by zero, but I can't find it in my code. Can u guide me what causes this error?

```
int main() {
    int input, base, newBase, convertion;

    scanf("%d %d", &input, &base);

    newBase = base;

    for ( ; input / base != 0; ) {
        base *= newBase;
    }

    for ( int reminder = input % base; base > 1; reminder %= base ) {
        base = base / newBase;
        convertion = reminder / base;
        printf("%d", convertion);
    }
    printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your code? What line exactly causes the exception? Does it happen for all input data or for some input data? etc etc ...

Comment: is it happening for some inputs or for all

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when you input base as 0 and therefore `input / base` is invalid because of division with `0`.

You should implement code to avoid this for example with a loop that asks for input until it is correct:

```
do{
        scanf("%d", &base);
        newBase = base;
  }while( base <= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SIGFPE` signal is caused by fatal arithmetic errors; including integer and floating point arithmetic errors; and including division by zero and overflow.

On 80x86 CPUs, if an (integer) division overflows it causes the same "divide error" exception as division by zero; so it's natural for kernels to map both causes (and also the various floating point exceptions) to the `SIGFPE` signal. In addition, division and modulo are the same instruction (`div` and `idiv` both return a quotient and remainder), so you can end up with SIGFPE from integer modulo too.

If the user enters "base = 0" you'd get division by zero in `input / base`. If the user enters "base = 1" you'd end up with an infinite loop. If the user enters a negative base, then I don't even want to think about what might happen.

If the user enters a large value for `input` (e.g. the equivalent of `INT_MAX`) it's very likely you'll get an infinite loop; because `base *= newBase` overflows and therefore `input / base != 0` never stops the loop.

For the last problem; if `base` is a power of 2 (e.g. 2, 4, 8, ...) then the `base *= newBase` can/will overflow such that base becomes zero; causing a division by zero after that.